# Repeat a template on every click of a button using knock out js and to save data of the templates

Tags: knockout.js

I have a template which has to be repeated on every click of a button.The template has set of text boxes and checkboxes.The user input of the repeated templates has to saved and repopulated on retrieval using knock out js..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! At the moment your question is too broad - can you tell us what you have tried so far and what *specific* problem you had with that approach?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start with is [KnockoutJS Tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com). here you can learn to to use KnockoutJS in effective way.
If you wanna just head to your question kindly check these:

[Working with Lists and Collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections)